# I2C Temperature Sensor Communication Issue

Tags: i2c, communication, temperature-sensor

I'm currently learning I2C and having some issues displaying the correct temperature in the serial monitor.

I am using an Arduino Uno and an SI7021 temperature sensor from Sparkfun; here's [the datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Weather/Si7021.pdf) I'm looking at.

The datasheet says that its device address is `0x40` and the temperature register is `0xF3` (maybe I am looking at this wrong?). However when I print the result to the screen it reads -1 degrees F.

Here's my code:

```
// SparkFun Si7021 Humidity and Temperature Sensor
#include <SparkFun_Si7021_Breakout_Library.h>
#include <Wire.h>

//Weather sensor slave address
int WeatherAddress = 0x40;

#define Temperature_Register_DATA 0xF3

//initialize humidity and temperature variables
float humidity = 0;
float tempf = 0;

//create a sensor from the Weather library
Weather temp_rh_sensor;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //create wire object
  Wire.begin();
  //begin weather sensor
  temp_rh_sensor.begin();
}

void loop() {
  //begin transmission to weather sensor
  Wire.beginTransmission(WeatherAddress);
  //ask particular register for data (temperature register)
  Wire.write(Temperature_Register_DATA);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  //request the transmitted single byte from the register
  Wire.requestFrom(Temperature_Register_DATA, 1);
  if(Wire.available() <= 1) {
    tempf = Wire.read();
  }
  Serial.print("Temp: ");
  Serial.print(tempf);
  Serial.println("F, ");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: You have connected a 3.3V sensor to a 5V Arduino Uno via the sda and scl lines ? Did you use a i2c voltage level shifter ? Did you connect 5V or 3.3V to the + connection of the module ? The sensor could be broken by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading this sensor is a little more involved. You don't just select a register and then read the value from it. Instead you send it a command to begin a read of a parameter (e.g., temperature) and then you need to wait for it to perform that command before you can read the result.

You need to use command 0xF3 for read with *no hold master mode* which will return NACK from a read request if the command isn't completed (which you are doing) - you then need to keep retrying the read until you don't get a NACK.

Also you need to read *two* bytes, not one:

```
//begin transmission to weather sensor
Wire.beginTransmission(WeatherAddress);

//ask particular register for data (temperature register)
Wire.write(Temperature_Register_DATA);

Wire.endTransmission();


// Keep retrying the read until it succeeds, or times out
uint32_t start = millis();
while (Wire.requestFrom(WeatherAddress, 2) < 2) {
    if (millis() - start > 2000) { // 2 second timeout
        break;
    }
}

if (Wire.available() < 2) { // It timed out
    Serial.println("Timeout");
} else {
    // Read the two bytes
    uint8_t hi = Wire.read();
    uint8_t lo = Wire.read();

    // and combine them into a 16 bit value
    uint16_t temp = (hi << 8) | lo;

    // Now convert the returned value into a real temperature:
    tempf = ((175.25 * temp) / 65536.0) - 46.85
    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    Serial.println(tempf);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Wire.requestFrom(Temperature_Register_DATA, 1);
```

This should have the WeatherAddress as parameter instead of the register.

```
Wire.requestFrom(WeatherAddress, 1);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I just gave this a shot but it is still spitting out a -1 for the temperature. Does this mean I'm just accessing the wrong register inside the sensor?

Answer (score 0):

> The datasheet says that its device address is: 0x40

there is no standard notation on how to code i2c addresses - it all depends on how the particular library is coded. In this case, try 0x80 and 0x40 and see which one works.

Comment: The datasheet is quite clear... "The 7-bit base slave address is 
0x40". It even goes so far as to depict it in an entire byte showing the bits of the address (1000000) and the RW bit.